# JQuery Issue: .datepicker is not a function?

Tags: jquery, jquerydatetimepicker

The requirement is to use jquery datepicker when textbox is clicked. All the js references is added but still .datepicker is not a function error comes up. The code is given below. Am i missing out on something?

**Error Details**

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (Index:56)
at c (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:21)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:21)
at Function.ready (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:21)
at HTMLDocument.q (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:21)
```

**Code:**

```
 @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
  }
<!-- Include Date Range Picker -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Content/bootstrap-datepicker.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js">    </script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({ format: 'dd/mm/yyyy', autoclose: true, todayBtn: 'linked' });
  });
</script>

 <h3>BootStrap Datetime Picker Example</h3>
<hr />
<div>Click textbox to open datetime picker: <input type="text" id="fromDate" class="datepicker" /></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery.datetimepicker.js">   </script>
```

Comment: you're commented 
@*<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/bootstrap-  datepicker.min.js"></script>*@

Comment: remove the comment and also space in it between bootstrap-datepicker
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

Comment: @ImranSaleem : I am not using bootstrap datepicker - using jquery ui date time picker  I have edited the coed now.

Comment: Did you load jquery ui?? https://jqueryui.com/  `datepicker` is in jquery ui library which is on top of the jquery framework. And your datetimepicker seems that is an other library which is on top of  jquery ui

Comment: try to load the jquery ui first, then load datetimepicker.js

Comment: @JackyShek - i have added that reference also. but still it is failing. I have also moved the datetimepicker.js reference to the bottom. but it is still failing.

Comment: if you follow https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/, it must be work. It must be another error on your code when you setting wrong on `datepicker`

Comment: can you provide the ***datetimepicker.js*** link to let me try?

Comment: please make simple demo as your projects ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're loading datepicker.js before the page has loaded jjquery-ui.css, jquery-1.12.4.js and query-ui.js. Place it below them, otherwise it can't extend their functionality.

Comment: I have moved the jquery.datetimepicker.js reference to the bottom of the cshtml. but still the issue persists

Comment: Works fine now. Had to move the js and css to the bottom of layout.cshtml page. Thanks

Comment: @SunilA actually the problem is that  you loaded the js sequence not move the js or css problem

Comment: @JackyShek : Thanks, Correct. I loaded js first which was required by the code.